# how to get the image inserted by the user using summernote and upload it on disk in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, json, summernote

I am using a summernote in bootstrap as my editor. It looks good and I'm fond using it.  I can get the texts inserted by the user, however, the problem is that when the user inserted an image, the src of image returns to a binary text. I dont want to save this whole text of the src into the database, instead, I want the image to be saved directly to my disk drive and copy the image name and save it into the database.

Does anybody know this?

Thanks

Comment: *Call* the function (`()`).

Answer (score 1):

```
var weblayout = {
  data : { 
    rows : function() {
        return 1;
    } 
  }     
};

weblayout.data.rows();// call the function row()
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xLhu2qot/)

or

```
var weblayout = {
  data : { 
    rows : function() {
        return 1;
    } 
  }     
};

var fctRow = weblayout.data.rows();// call the function row()
alert(fctRow);
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/6aqreg1w/)

Answer (score 0):

### Using Summernote Image Button

This is a little snippet i use for my cms.

#### Integrate on image upload function to summernote

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.editor').summernote({
        height: 300,
        toolbar: [
                ['style', ['style']],
                ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'strikethrough', 'superscript', 'subscript', 'clear']],
                ['fontname', ['fontname']],
                ['fontsize', ['fontsize']],
                ['color', ['color']],
                ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                ['height', ['height']],
                ['table', ['table']],
                ['insert', ['link', 'picture', 'video', 'hr', 'readmore']],
                ['genixcms', ['elfinder']],
                ['view', ['fullscreen', 'codeview']],
                ['help', ['help']]
            ],
        onImageUpload: function(files, editor, welEditable) {
                sendFile(files[0],editor,welEditable);
            }
    });

    function sendFile(file,editor,welEditable) {
      data = new FormData();
      data.append("file", file);
        $.ajax({
            url: "saveimage.php",
            data: data,
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(data){
            alert(data);
              $('.editor').summernote('editor.insertImage', data);
            },
           error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
             console.log(textStatus+" "+errorThrown);
           }
        });
    }

    $(".alert").alert();
});
```

This snippet will make the image upload dialog send the file into the disk. But to handle that you must create the php file which will handle the image upload. 
See this little code for my cms

#### Saveimage PHP file

```
$url = "http://yoursite.com";
$allowed = array('png');

if(isset($_FILES['file']) && $_FILES['file']['error'] == 0){
    $extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(!in_array(strtolower($extension), $allowed)){
        echo '{"status":"error"}';
        exit;
    }
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], GX_PATH.'/assets/images/uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'])){
        $tmp= '/assets/images/uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        echo $url.'/assets/images/uploads/'.$_FILES['file']['name'];
        //echo '{"status":"success"}';
        exit;
    }
}
```

This php file will save the file into the path. for inserting it into your databse i think you know already.

i hope this will help for you or for anyone had the same problem.

### Using elFinder File Manager

for using elFinder file manager. please see this answer. 
[How to add image manager in Summernote WYSIWYG editor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27905207/how-to-add-image-manager-in-summernote-wysiwyg-editor/31282602#31282602)

Thank You,

Comment: How can we upload image to our server from URL directly with Summernote?